# How to add a bool to request.security()?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How i can add a bool to request.security?
So I can try to choose between a and b
examples:

```
a = request.security(symbol, timeframe, expression, gaps, lookahead, ignore_invalid_symbol)    
b = request.security(symbol, timeframe, expression, gaps, lookahead, ignore_invalid_symbol)    
c = a or/ and b

plot(c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#ternary-operator) for that.

```
bool choose_a = true

a = request.security(symbol, timeframe, expression, gaps, lookahead, ignore_invalid_symbol)    
b = request.security(symbol, timeframe, expression, gaps, lookahead, ignore_invalid_symbol)    
c = choose_a ? a : b  // if choose_a is true, use a. Else, use b

plot(c)
```

Comment: Thank you ...  :)  what if i have a , b , c, d , e .... more than just a and b ...     c = ??

Comment: Then you can use nested if statements for each combination.